# Get and Set methods in generics class implementing IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, generics, ienumerable

I have a class implementing generics and IEnumerable

```
public class MyEnumClass<T> : IEnumerable<MyEnumClass<T>>
{
   public T Data
   {
     get { return this.Data; } 
     set 
        {
          Data = value;
        }
    }

 public MyEnumClass(T data)
 {
   Data = data;
  }
}
```

I would like to implement some logic inside the set method (or in some other way, whenever my Data gets changed). Without commenting the line `Data = value` I get StackOverflow. With the line: `Data = value` commented out at least the instantiation works, but only when using a string as generics:

```
var foo = new MyEnumClass<string>("Foo");
```

However, as soon as I try to plug into  my own object:

```
var foo = new MyEnumClass<MyOwnObjectType>(InstanceOfMyOwnObjectType);
```

I get "Unable to read memory"
How can I properly define get/set methods so that I could use `MyOwnObjectType` instead of T/string when instantiating?

Comment: The first problem I can see is that you have a stack overflow exception. When you set `this.Data` inside the setter for `Data` your setter is calling itself recursively.  Instead you need to add some private field `T data;` and use that as the backing field for `Data`, i.e. `get { return this.data; } ` and `set { this.data = value; }`  See: [Stack overflow exception in C# setter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3276156) and [How to avoid property recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19682999).

Answer (score 0):

you need to create an explicit backing field

```
public class MyEnumClass<T> : IEnumerable<MyEnumClass<T>>
{
    T m_data;
    public T Data
    {
        get { return this.m_data; } 
        set 
        {
            m_data = value;
        }
    }

    public MyEnumClass(T data)
    {
            Data = data;
    }
}
```